# Collapsing toolbar layout with viewpager and swipeRefreshLayout inside a fragment of viewpager

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I am using Collapsing ToolBar Layout with viewpager and having different fragments for each tab. Now in one of the fragments of tabs I am having swipeRefreshLayout.

So, whenever I scrollup it works perfect but when scroll down the swipeRefreshLayout start working and the collapsing effect does not work in this case.

So, can you please help me here, how can I resolve this issue. Thank you so much in advanced.